# strncpy() random result

Tags: c, strncpy

This should copy a string but prints garbled results. Can anyone help me out?

```
int main () {       

    const char *a = "Hello\n";
    const char *b = "World\n";

    strncpy(&b, &a, strlen(a)); 
    printf("%s %s", a, b);  
    return 0;

}
```

I expect "Hello Hello" but the terminal prints:

```
\
    Hello
```

GCC prints an warning about a and b having incompatible pointer types even though strncpy's signature:

```
char * strncpy(char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n)
```

asks for 2 char pointers. Is that because arrays are always char** as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20213168 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `char **` twice where `char*` is expected.

`&b` takes the address of `b`, with `b` being a `char*`, the address of a `char`. So `&b` is `char **`. The same issue appears for `a`.

---

**Update:**

Just saw `b` isn't an array but a pointer which points to a "string"-literal. The latter are constant, you cannot change them, so copying to a literal's address (what the code actually does **not**, because of the misplaced `&`-operator in frot of the `b`) has to fail.

To get around this define `b` like this

```
char b [] = "World\n";
```

---

> Is that because arrays are always char** [...]

Arrays **aren't** "*always `char **`*".

If an array is passed as argument to a function it decays to a pointer to it's first element. So

```
char b[] = "test";
```

would decay to a

```
char * pb
```

with `pb` pointing to the `char` `'t'`, the first characters of `"test".

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

1. You should not copy into a buffer pointed by `const char *`, as it is a constant buffer.
2. The arguments for `strncpy` are `char *`s, but you passed `char **`, thus overwriting the pointers themselves, not the content they point to.

Comment: 3. You should not copy to even a non-const `char*` that points to a string literal, as it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @FredLarson - true, but it's actually "you should not assign `const char *` to `char *`". One cannot **simply** distinguish constant memory areas...

Comment: Agreed, but compilers will often let you get away with it.

Comment: It's not the `const` that is the issue (although not nice it might work). The issue is that `b` is pointing to a literal.

Comment: @alk - If you dig into the execution itself, it might not be the type of the pointer that matters, though the type of the pointer will probably not exist anymore in the execution stage. But C as a language has rules, and one of them is that `const char *` is not `char *`, and that's what matters when writing C, and it doesn't matter if the const char * points to constant memory or not. It's as simple as that. String literal is just an instance of const memory for that matter.

Comment: I fully agree ... @MByD (but leave my comment as a base/background for others to understand the motivation of your comment) Anyhow have my +1, for sticking to and pointing out the rules! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Compile your code with `-Wall` to see warnings that will tell you how to fix this.

Comment: Although the second part of your sentence is more a wish, the first is essential! 1+ ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

1) You should use `strncpy(a, b, strlen(a))`, if `a` is a `char*` and `b` a `const char*`. The compiler error you're getting alludes to this.

2) You have *undefined behaviour*. You've allocated `const char*` string *literals*. A compiler may put them in read-only memory. And an attempt to modify either of them is not allowed: even a single element change could cause a program crash.

One remedy would be to use `char* b = malloc(/*ToDo - your size here*/);`. Remember to `free` the memory once you're done with it.

Comment: What's the point of using strncpy if you are just going to throw a strlen in there with it?  buffer overload perk: re-enabled!